# Billion Matchsticks

Tags: matches

A little twist on the "move the matchsticks" puzzle.

I placed a bunch of matchsticks on my kitchen table and formed a number with them (6,111,100). I am asking, how can you move just two matchsticks, so that you get a number as close as possible to one billion (1,000,000,000)?

[image]

Remark: Thanks to Mr Pie for awarding a bounty to Deusovi. His answer was the intended one, but BreakingMyself provided a similar one first; that's the reason I gave him the checkmark.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my expansion of this puzzle and usage of your image: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/dont-settle-for-a-billion

Comment: @AdamDavis of course not, our goal is to help each other build better puzzles here:)

Comment: Moving 4 matches i can make GOGOL.  Waaay more than a billion!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A quick and dirty answer, hopefully this is it!:

> [image]

As you can see, just two matches moved to create '1,000,000,000' :)

Comment: Can't be any other answer, actually. Was just going to write this. You were faster. Haha =D @BreakingMyself

Comment: The intended answer is posted by @Deusovi below, but BreakingMyself first posted the correct idea.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the kindness but if @Deusovi is more accurate I'd hate to steal the answer away over a technicality.

Comment: @Deusovi has a billion accepted answers already, I don't think he would mind it:)

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan is right - I really don't mind! And your answer is just as valid.

Comment: It took me way to long to figure out why you have the same table as the OP...

Comment: I honestly can't see it, how does it show the number 1,000,000,000?

Comment: NEVERMIND I GET IT. AHAHA

Comment: @Annabelle Bit of a sneaky one lol

Answer (score 42):

Similar to [BreakingMyself's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/53465/34836), but I think this is what you were looking for:

> [image: Matchsticks arranged as 'billion']

Comment: How dare you ;)

Comment: This was my intended answer, but I will have to give the credit to @BreakingMyself, since he first posted the idea:)

Comment: Surely this can be done moving only 1 match if you use a Capital B and Small L (l)?

Comment: @Weckar E. I thought about this when I was making the puzzle, but it would make 'l' and 'i' look the same, and also '8' and 'b' look the same. I think the characters Deusovi used are more or less the standard ones.

Comment: Congratulations!! $\boxed{\color{blue}{+100}}$ :D

Answer (score 11):

[image: 611,111,110]

if the answer is to be of numeric form, this is closest i can think of. 611,111,110

Comment: use one of the matches to form an 8 from the 6

Comment: where do you get the additional match?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on whether the *_numbers_* must conform to seven segment display format the first image is correct. If only digits are allowed (no alpha chars you cheaters!) but don't need to conform to the seven segment display format, the second is more correct.

[image: Non-cheating solution moving two matchsticks from number 6,111,100 to number closest to 1,000,000,000]